# Detect when tableView is at the bottom lagging

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've created a tableView which is hooked up to a api. i'm trying to implement a load more functionality where it make a new api call when you reach the bottom of the tableView. i've created this functionality, but when there is not anymore objects in the api/json file. it seem to be very laggy when i reach the bottom how come is that?

detecting when i'm at the bottom at the screen and doing a api call

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {



    var height = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    var contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    var distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;

    if distanceFromBottom < height
    {
        if isApiCalling == false {
            getRecent("URL/recent.php?lastid=\(lastObjectIndex)&limit=\(numberOfRecordsPerAPICall)")
            self.tableVIew.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

GetRecent function. i've even created a isAPICalling variable, which makes sure that it does not run the api several times.

```
func getRecent(url: NSString) {

    isApiCalling = true
    let recentUrl = NSURL(string: url as String)
    var recentRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: recentUrl!)
    var recentData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(recentRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

    let jsonArray = JSON(data: recentData!)
    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {
        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
        var newNewsObject = News(id: subJson["id"].intValue, title: subJson["title"].stringValue, link: subJson["url"].stringValue, imageLink: subJson["image_url"].stringValue, summary: subJson["news_text"].stringValue, date: getDate(subJson["date"].stringValue))



        recentArray.append(newNewsObject)
    }

    lastObjectIndex = lastObjectIndex + numberOfRecordsPerAPICall
    isApiCalling = false


}
```

Comment: https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl (objc project)

Comment: Do you have any idea whether it is possible to use in a swift project? using the bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add footer to the tableview section, if the footer get load then call the next set by API calls, (load footer only if `flag`==-1)

While request next set, you can set flag (like `flag`=1), that call has been made already, so if user scroll up and down again, request will not be send (if `flag`==1).

In response, set flag back to normal (like `flag`=0), and check response, if there is no more data, set flag for not loading footer ever (like `flag`=-1).

P.S. Make sure `flag` is 0 while view loads first time.

May solve your problem with such way.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: I'm not sure i'm quite understanding why add a footer?

Comment: If your tableview has only 1 section, so the sectionsfooter will be load at last when all cell (`numberofcellforsection`) has been loaded sucessfully, 
So you can set your loading more animation or msg by custom footer and load new bunch of data when footer gets load,